# Can I know if my app is allowed to pair with unpaired devices in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using `BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher` to watch for Bluetooth low energy beacons.
If user has disabled option "Communicate with unpaired devices" (`ms-settings:privacy-customdevices`), my app will never get any beacon.

Is it possible to check if this option is enabled, or ask user to enable this option?

Comment: You can use AppCapability.CheckAccess to see whether you have access to a particular capability, or AppCapability.RequestAccessAsync which will prompt the user for permission if the user has not yet granted or blocked access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found a way to check directly, but if the user disables this option, calling the `Start` method of the watcher, it will immediately be aborted with error code `DisabledByUser`. You can see this in action in the [Bluetooth Advertisment sample in UWP samples repo](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothAdvertisement).

You can subscribe to the `Stopped` event on the watcher and then check the `BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherStoppedEventArgs.Error` to see if the user disabled it:

```
private async void OnAdvertisementWatcherStopped(
    BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher, 
    BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherStoppedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    if (watcher.Status == BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherStatus.Aborted)
    {
        if (eventArgs.Error == BluetoothError.DisabledByUser) 
        { 
           // do something - show dialog to open settings, etc.
        }
    }
}
```

You can ask the user to enable the app access with a dialog message and redirect them to the Settings app by executing `Launch.LaunchUriAsync("ms-settings:privacy-customdevices")`.